# How to show loading indicator on change route query in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have project with routes. When I go, for example, from the link `http://localhost:3000/product/kartiny/18142` to link `http://localhost:3000/product/frame/18142` i see loading indicator like this:

[image]

But when i only change query on link, for example from `http://localhost:3000/catalog/kartiny?product=kartiny&sort_by=views_count&pages=3` to `http://localhost:3000/catalog/kartiny?product=kartiny&sort_by=views_count&pages=4` i don't see it

How i can force to show it ?

Comment: are you using `axios` or `$axios` for sending requests?

Comment: When you do change the path, it's by typing it in the browser directly or by using `nuxt-link`?

Comment: @fevid i'm using axios

Comment: @kissu in first case it `nuxt-link`, in second it works `this.$router.push({ query: q });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `nuxt-link` or `$router`, you will not have any kind of loader.
This one happens when making external requests using `fetch()` or `asyncData()`.
If you're changing path, this is not an axios call, hence no progress bar.

You can trigger the progress bar manually with this kind of code

```html
<script>
export default {
  fetch() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$nuxt.$loading.start()
      // eslint-disable-next-line nuxt/no-timing-in-fetch-data
      setTimeout(() => this.$nuxt.$loading.finish(), 2000)
    })
  },
}
</script>
```

Still, I'm not sure that this is useful besides having a visual loader.
This is more to have a YouTube like behavior, showing the user that the page is loading if he pressed a button and his connection is on the slow side.
[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thi4e.gif) of the behavior done by YouTube.

---

More details can be found here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/loading#programmatically-starting-the-loading-bar

Answer (score 1):

loading indicator works either with navigating to pages which have `asyncData` or `fetch` (when rendering) in it.

since you are changing the query and using `methods` for getting data you should use `$axios` instead of `axios` which will add same loading animation as navigation for requests.

for example replace `axios.get` with `this.$axios.$get`.